# How does Fourier work with arbitrary FourierParameters?

Tags: fourier-analysis, algorithm

Mathematica's `Fourier` function allows you to insert an arbitrary real number in the exponent of the discrete Fourier transform, via `FourierParameters`, so that the transform becomes something like $$ \sum_{j=1}^n u_j e^{2\pi i b (j-1)(k-1)/n} $$ with $b$ arbitrary.

I find this very useful in my work, but I don't understand how it works.  The usual description of the FFT algorithm (e.g. as outlined in "Numerical Recipes") depends in an essential way on the $n$-periodicity of exponential factor.  When I insert an arbitrary $b$ and call `Fourier`, am I still getting a fast Fourier transform?  Or is it secretly doing a slow DFT?  In the former case, how does Mathematica get around the need for a periodic exponential factor?

Comment: The documentation to `Fourier` in the "Details and Options" section clearly says "To ensure a unique inverse discrete Fourier transform, `Abs[b]` must be relatively prime to n. »" and "Some common choices for {a,b} are {0,1} (default), {-1,1} (data analysis), {1,-1} (signal processing). ".

Comment: @user64494 That's not relevant to the question here though.  `Fourier` still computes the transform of a sequence, even if the choice of parameters mean that the transform is not invertable.  The question is how it does that, and in particular whether the transform is still "fast" ($O(n \log(n))$).  Also, there are many values of `FourierParameters` which make the transform still invertable (i.e. no warning is shown), but would seem to break the naive FFT algorithm.  If anything, this makes it even more mysterious how `Fourier` does what it does.

Comment: I think`Fourier` is simply meaningless in that case. Can you ground "Also, there are many values of FourierParameters which make the transform still invertable (i.e. no warning is shown), but would seem to break the naive FFT algorithm. "? TIA.

Comment: There are references [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_discrete_Fourier_transform) I have used this to interpolate a Fourier spectrum. There is an example of using it in the Mathematica GuideBook for Numerics p 245

Comment: @Hugh: What do you mean by "this"? Please indicate these references among 15 items . Can you give a link to  the Mathematica GuideBook for Numerics p 245? TIA.

Comment: By "this" I mean putting in a number for b in the `FourierParameters`.  A [link](http://www.mathematicaguidebooks.org/) to the guidebooks. If I can find the time I will add an example of what I have done.

Comment: @Hugh: Thank you for your constructive reply.

Comment: A possible implementation can be based on [ffrft (unit circle CZT)](https://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/fracfft.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use `FourierParameters` for interpolating a spectrum.
First we generate some data, take the ordinary Fourier transform and plot.

```
data = Table[Sin[\[Pi] k/33], {k, 256}] // N;
ListLinePlot[data]
ft = Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];
ListLinePlot[Abs@ft[[1 ;; 128]], PlotRange -> All]
ListPlot[Abs@ft[[1 ;; 20]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

The last, expanded view of the spectrum shows that there are rather few points defining the peak.

The following `Dynamic` enables the interpolation to be seen when `FourierParameters` are altered. The actual frequency and the magnitude of the Fourier peak should be

```
 (*   {0.0151515, 0.511146}   *)

DynamicModule[{b = 1, pos, a = 0, ft, freqs},
 ft = Abs@Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {-1, b}];
 pos = Position[ft, Max[ft]][[1, 1]];
 freqs = Table[(n - 1)/Length[data], {n, Length[data]}];
 Column[{
   Dynamic[
    Row[{"Frequency (Hz) = ", a[[1]], "     Magnitude = ", a[[2]] }]],
   Dynamic@ListLinePlot[Transpose[{freqs, ft}], PlotRange -> All,
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], 
       Point[a = Transpose[{freqs, ft}][[pos]]]},
     ImageSize -> 12 72, Frame -> True, Mesh -> All],
   Slider[Dynamic[b, {b = #;
       ft = Abs@Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {-1, b}];
       freqs = Table[b (n - 1)/Length[data], {n, Length[data]}];
       pos = Position[ft, Max[ft]][[1, 1]]
       } &], {0, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

As you can see we can get many more points into the peak and have thus interpolated the spectrum. Thus we can more accurately work out the frequency.

Hope that helps.

Comment: To clarify: I know how to do this. What I'm asking is not "How to use FourierParameters?", but rather "How does Mathematica implement FourierParameters without breaking the $n\log(n)$ scaling of the FFT algorithm?". I guess this reply is still helpful for clarifying to others what FourierParameters is capable of, but it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation based on [Bailey's paper](https://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/fracfft.pdf).

```
ClearAll[ffrft$set] ;
ffrft$set[length_, span_] := Block[
{trig, work},
trig =Exp[I*Pi*span/length*Range[0.0, length-1]^2] ;
work = Fourier[Flatten[{Conjugate[trig] , Exp[-I*Pi*span/length*Range[-length, -1.0]^2]}] , FourierParameters -> {1, 1} ];
{trig, work}
] ;

ClearAll[ffrft$get] ;
ffrft$get[length_, signal_, trig_, work_] := Block[
{ffrft},
ffrft = ConstantArray[0.0, 2*length]  ;
ffrft[[1;;length]] = trig*signal ;
ffrft = work*Fourier[ffrft, FourierParameters -> {1, 1} ] ;
ffrft =Fourier[ffrft, FourierParameters -> {1, -1} ][[1;;length]] ;
ffrft*trig/(2*length)
] ;
```

Example:

```
length = 1024 ;
signal = Sin[2*Pi*0.12345*Range[length]] ;
b = 1/Sqrt[2.0]  ;
{trig, work} = ffrft$set[length, b]  ;
ref = Fourier[signal, FourierParameters -> {1, b}] ;
res = ffrft$get[length, signal, trig, work] ;
ref-res // Chop // DeleteDuplicates
(* {0} *)
```

Timing:

```
length = 8192 ;
signal = Sin[2*Pi*0.12345*Range[length]] ;
b = 1/Sqrt[2.0]  ;
t$ref = First@RepeatedTiming[Fourier[signal, FourierParameters -> {1, b}] ];
t$res = First@RepeatedTiming[{trig, work} = ffrft$set[length, b]  ; ffrft$get[length, signal, trig, work] ];
t$ref/t$res
```

For `FourierParameters -> {1, 1}` WM is most likely uses FFT from MKL, while
for `FourierParameters -> {a, b}` it is not clear. While it is possible to compute with `n*log(n)`, I'm not sure it is the case in WM.